# How can I ask if they are bothered by me not being japanese?

Tags: questions

I am playing a Japanese game and I accidentally joined a team. In the chat the other players welcomed me, but how do I answer them and how can I ask them if they are bothered by the fact that I only know a tiny bit Japanese?

I tried to write a comment myself and this is what I ended up with: 字が読めません
 初ぬまして 私はオランダ人です. But I don't know if this is correct ^^;

(I also couldn't find a translation for my question if they are bothered by the fact that I only know a tiny bit Japanese. Does anyone know how I could say that?)

Comment: You need to edit this question with what you think might be the correct wording, what you've researched, etc., or it will likely be closed.

Comment: @istrasci Thank you for telling me, I changed it.

Comment: I have no idea about the Japanese game, but it is an online game, isn't it? You don't speak, hear, write and read Japanese, but you can join the game, right? If so, what you have to do is just write "I'm a Dutch and I don't read and write Japanese. If nesessary, please communicate in English. By the way "初めまして（not ぬ but め）、私はオランダ人です。日本語は分かりません。英語でお願いします。お手数かけます。is fine.

Comment: I would change the order of your attempt. At the moment it says "I can't read Japanese. Hi, I'm from the Netherlands."

Comment: @Sonny365TANAKA Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Earthliŋ Thanks for telling me, I hadn't noticed it.

Comment: You could also totally say this in simple English, and they could most likely read and understand it.

Comment: I usually resort to 「ちょっとだけ日本語をわかります。英語はいいですか。」or similar, not that I need to very often .. .:)

Answer (score 3):

There's a pretty strong chance that whoever it is will have studied more English than you've studied Japanese, so your best bet is to simply say. "I don't speak Japanese. Can I still play?" or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all Japanese can't talk in English, but can read English sentences if they are simple.  I hope you can communicate with the game members in English and you could learn more Japanese phrases automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind! It's a game. Game itself can't kill you nor devastate your life even if you can't speak in Japanese. 
Wat zijn moet, dat zal zo zijn.

Comment: Does that last bit end up as "Que Sera..."/"What will be, will be"?

Comment: @William-Rem yes it does. It's Dutch. Bet you know wat I mean by that.